# Отфильтровать строки из текстового файла на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как решить задачу такого плана - В текстовом файле имеются строки:

```
Документ №Ra2343 создан - 15.06.2017
Документ №Ra2544 создан - 10.06.2018
Документ создан 21.06.2018
Документ создан 22.06.2019
Документ №Ra2542 создан - 10.06.2018
Документ создан 15.06.2019
```

Отсеять все строки из файла где нет знака "**№**" и знака "**-**" и на выходе создается файл в котором результат:

```
Документ №Ra2343 создан - 15.06.2017
Документ №Ra2544 создан - 10.06.2018
Документ №Ra2542 создан - 10.06.2018
```

Отсеять по одному ключевому слову я знаю:

**Делаю так - это поиск строк по одному слову:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
fall, f1: TextFile;
S: string;
begin
//Открываем диалог выбора файла
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
     AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog1.FileName);
     reset(fall);
     AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Reaultat.txt');
     rewrite(f1);
     end;

//работаем по строкам в файле
 while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
 //читаем строку
  ReadLn(fall, S);
// В memo пишем ключевое слово и ищем все строки с ним без учета регистра
  if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Memo1.Lines[0]), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
  writeln(f1, S);
   end;
CloseFile(fall);
CloseFile(f1);
end;
end.
```

А вот как искать строку по (двум словам) параметрам, то есть если есть знак "**№**" и знак "**-**" (Обязательно эти два знака в строке)) то записываем строку в Reaultat.txt ?

Comment: А вы можете добавить код, как вы это делаете по одному слову, а мы уже вам поможем сделать, чтобы было по 2м?

Comment: @Axenow, Сделала, добавила код в тему. Посмотрите пожалуйста...

Comment: Я не эксперт по pascal, но по аналогии вы можете сделать вот так: `if (Pos('№', AnsiLowerCase(s)) == 0 and Pos('-', AnsiLowerCase(s)) == 0) then` не сработает разве?

Comment: @Axenow, Увы, так не срабатывает...

Comment: Прошу прощения, неверно прочитал условие. Надо чтобы оба знака были: `if (Pos('№', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0 and Pos('-', AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then`. Вот так должно быть,

Comment: Вам помогут регулярные выражения

Comment: @Axenow, Огромнейшее спасибо - все сработало только так :). !

Comment: @Татьяна Я очень надеюсь, что вы поняли, что происходит в этом коде.

Comment: @Axenow, Да, то я просто не включила свой мозг, можно было же догадаться. То есть там происходит условие если в строке есть знак № и знак - то значит она записывается, если нет то не записывается. Большущее спасибо!

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/21599097/1216425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Delphi XE уже включен модуль работы с регулярными выражениями, можно воспользоваться именно этим механизмом

```
Uses
  ....
  RegularExpressions;
  ....
Begin
  ....
  RegEx:=TRegEx.Create('^Документ\s№[^\s]+\sсоздан\s-\s\d+\.\d+\.\d+$');
  ....
  while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
    ....
    ReadLn(fall, S);
    if(RegEx.IsMatch(S)) then //Что делаем если есть совпадение
    ....
  end;
  ....
end;
```

Comment: а `TStringList` то где?

Comment: @teran, а он тут нужен? или по вашему я освоил только TStringList из всего многообразия стандартных контролов? или вас так сильно задел прошлый пример с ним?))

Comment: @teran Давайте в следущем примере где нужна будет загрузка файла с указанием кодировки я потоком(tStream) воспользуюсь чтоб вам было что покритиковать?)

Comment: при чем тут указание кодировки. файлы с assign читали в 90х годах прошлого века. можно ведь подсказать автору не только то, как решить конкретную проблему фильтрации строк, но и более простой способ чтения файла вообще. Очевидно, автор просто не знает о таких возможностях, ну или не помнит.
ваш прошлый пример вообще к делу не относится, пока вы не написали, я про это и не вспомнил даже.

Comment: @teran Хорошо, что по вашему плохого именно в таком чтении файла? для текстовых файлов имхо, это оптимальный способ чтения построчно. Можно прикрутить FileStream как более новый, но он тут избыточен, можно прикрутить более современный FileOpen, но он не дает такой простоты при построчном чтении, тогда зачем советовать то что здесь будет избыточно или слишком нагружено? p.s. каждый инструмент(будь он стар или нов) хорош только если использовать его и понимать как он работает... а то будем микроскопом гвозди забивать...

Comment: p.s. механизм досих пор существует - существует, не помечен как "устаревший\неподдерживаемый" - не помечен. с задачей справляется - справляется... так зачем его менять? а то потом мы получаем очередную абстракцию ради абстракции(не в пример этому вопросу, а вообще, достали просто программы которые тупят там где они должны летать)

Comment: @teran, А какой еще есть способ в данной ситуации. Мне просто интересно, потому и спрашиваю (на примере) ?

Comment: @Татьяна я вам в комментах к вопросу ссылку-ассоциацию скинул. там такая же задача. за исключением использования регулярных выражений

Comment: @teran, Да но там з загрузкой в память. Для больших файлов это не пойдет... Или может я что то не то поняла, извините заранее...

Comment: @Татьяна, есть 2 основных способа, и куча производных от них, с первым вы знакомы(assignFile), второй FileOpen, все остальные способы - производные от этих. есть еще третий способ, но он точно не актуален в такой задаче, это MemoryMappedFile, отображение содержимого файла в ОЗУ. Возможно упустил какие то способы, но помоему всё остальное производное от этих двух(трех).

Comment: @Татьяна вы же ничего не писали про объем вашего файла в вопросе.

Comment: @teran, согласна, это мой недочет. Но файлы на самом деле большие.